# Does the rendering process of Chrome browser really have the step of Render-tree Construction? Why is there no such step in devtools performance?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-app, web-performance

I have read a post, link here: [Render-tree Construction, Layout, and Paint](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/render-tree-construction)

A demo page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>No JS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://127.0.0.1:3000/static/css/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The Performance Panel:
[image]

Enlarge the red part:

[image]

As you see, there is no step of Render-tree Construction.

Why? Does the post wrong or the Render-tree Construction part is in Recalculate Style?

Comment: The render tree is an abstract term, not a step in the timeline. Both `layout` and `recalculate styles` are parts of it.

Comment: In that post, there are tow step:

> Combine the DOM and CSSOM into a render tree.
> Run layout on the render tree to compute geometry of each node.

It's not likely that `layout` is part of `render tree`

Comment: The render tree is not an activity, it's a structure, a tree of objects so there's no step in timeline that directly translates into it. The `Layout` and `recalculate styles` steps are performed on the render tree so these are the only *related* steps.

Comment: Ah, my first comment has lost the word "construction".

Comment: Sorry, I am still not understand. If render tree exits, there must be some steps that translate something to it. I want to know which steps do this and how can I inspect it in chrome devtools. @wOxxOm

Comment: Both `layout` and `recalculate styles` are parts of the process that constructs the render-tree. The tree itself is not shown in devtools and never was. The article just explains what happens under the hood.